# Limit jQuery search to specific containers like h and p tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have this glossary page design with a search filter. I just noticed the filter is filtering based on all the html and not just the title and p tags. For example if put an image that had a file name of hello.jpg and i searched hello. It would also filter that. So its reading all the html. I just want it to filter based on the H tag and P tags or just the specific tags/classes i set. Whatever is easier.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my script so far

```
$("#txtSearch").on('keyup', function() {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    //Go through each list item and hide if not match search

    $(".list-group-item").each(function() {
        if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();  
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find` (`.find("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5")`) function just before using `.html()`.

Comment: @KYSSE glad I could help!